# jquery 'Request header field token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers'

Tags: javascript, cors

I am doing a file upload via AJAX. However, I am getting this error:

```
Request header field token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers
```

Here's the response headers from the website I am uploading to, and the response headers all seem fine:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, X-Prototype-Version, Content-Disposition, Cache-Control, Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://admin.lvho.st:9292
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 22 Jan 2014 03:01:25 UTC
Server: cloudinary
Status: 200 OK
X-Request-Id: 3a74ab61f56ae7620c8ffbb5440b75b6
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
transfer-encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
```

Here's the request headers:

```
OPTIONS /v1_1/*****/image/upload HTTP/1.1
Host: api.cloudinary.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://admin.lvho.st:9292
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.77 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, token, content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://admin.lvho.st:9292/venue/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Is there something missing/wrong in the response headers?

Thanks

Comment: You need to show the request headers as well if you'd like some help with this.  The request is likely including a header that is not acknowledged in the response's Access-Control-Allow-Headers, as the error message states.

Comment: @RayNicholus updated my post with request headers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Access-Control-Allow-Headers header in the response to the preflight (OPTIONS) is missing a reference to the "token" header.  You will need to update your server response  to account for this header.

Comment: Thanks, turned out 'token' was a header I was setting via ajax prefilter.